# Ruby/Rails - Can't access JSON object attributes directly in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I am setting up an API.

The client (using HTTParty) posts this to the API:

```
{:body => 
       {
        :product=> {:description=>"some text", :cost => "11.99"}, 
        :brand=>   {:name=>"BrandName", :etc =>"hey"}
       }
}
```

The server/api receives the post.
Now, if I access `params[:brand]` I get:

```
{"name"=>"BrandName", "etc" =>"hey"}
```

If I do this:

```
Brand.new(params[:brand])
```

Then I get a new Brand object with the "name" and "etc" attributes populated correctly.

However, if I try to access `params[:brand][:name]`, I just get `nil`

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `params[:brand]["name"]` or `params["brand"]["name"]`

Hash keys can be any sort of object. Common rails practice is to use symbols as hash keys, but when translated from JSON, the keys are likely to be strings.